# How to save a file without overriding the existing with same name

Tags: java, excel, file, rename

I am trying to save a file as *.xlsx without overwriting the existing file with the same name. I thought to add number suffixes to new file names, like file(1).xlsx, file(2).xlsx in case only if the specified file exists. Here what I have tried so far:

```
do {
  s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the name of the file name");
  File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents\\Challan_Reports\\" + s + ".xlsx");

  boolean exists = tmpDir.exists();
  if (exists) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "File Name Already exists try again!");

  }
  else {
    break;
  }
} while (true);
if (s.equals("") || s.equals(null)) {
  //.........................................................................
  File tmpDir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Documents\\Challan_Reports\\" + gname + " " + date + ".xlsx");
  boolean exists = tmpDir.exists();
  if (exists) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "exists 1");
    for (int m= 1; true;m++)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "exists m " + m);
      File tmpDir1 = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Documents\\Challan_Reports\\" + gname + " " + date + " (" + m + ").xlsx");
      System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Documents\\Challan_Reports\\" + gname + " " + date + " (" + m + ").xlsx");
      boolean exists1 = tmpDir1.exists();
      if (exists) {
        System.out.println("exists file");
        continue;
      }
      else {

        System.out.println(" not exists");
        filename = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Documents\\Challan_Reports\\" + gname + " " + date + " (" + m + ").xlsx";
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  //      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.home"),"Documents\\Challan_Reports\\"+gname+" "+date+".xlsx"));
  // workbook.write(out);
  // out.close();
}
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
System.out.println(
  "Writesheet.xlsx written successfully");
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, filename + ".xlsx \n\\Generated at path" + System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Documents\\Challan_Reports");
      }
     catch(Exception e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

The problem is that it gives the output as the file(1) or file(2)..... exists
when it doesn't. `If` condition in the loop works only the first time if I put the condition as `if(!exists)`. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing check mistake, instead checking for variable **exists1** , you are checking **exists** and that is true from before **for loop** part.

try changing as below.

```
boolean exists1 = tmpDir1.exists();
     if(exists1)// change here exists to exists1
     {
          System.out.println("exists file");
          continue;
     }
     else{

         System.out.println(" not exists");
         filename=System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Documents\\Challan_Reports\\"+gname+" "+date+" ("+m+").xlsx";
         break;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the condition where you are checking the file existence you are not doing anything right? Not appending anything in name hence if file exists, it will go ahead and try to save only the same name. Please try to append once you found the file existence